# Upload files to Sonatype Nexus 3 using Python

Tags: python, nexus3

I'm trying to figure out how to upload some `rpm` files to a Nexus 3 yum repository. Can't figure out how to configure the request call.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/yum-repositories#YumRepositories-DeployingPackagestoYumHostedRepositories), you can easily upload files to the hosted Yum repository using the `HTTP PUT` method.

An example of using the same using python:

```
import requests

files = {'file': open('yourfile.rpm', 'rb')}
response = requests.put('http://nexusURL/repository/yumRepo/yourfile.rpm', files=files, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

response = requests.put("https://example.com/repository/yum-local/yourfile.rpm", data=open('yourfile.rpm', 'rb'), auth=("admin_username", "admin_password"))
```